# Configuring vim-airline: Bad math expression

Tags: vim, zsh

I'm brand new to Vim and just trying to get setup with [vim-airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline). I'm using Pathogen to install and have followed the instructions provided. vim-airline is successfully cloned in `~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline`.

When I try to add the required `let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1` instruction to my `~/.vimrc` file I get the following error from the console when trying to source it:

> bad math expression: ':' without '?'

I'm running vim 8.0.134 on macOS Sierra with `zsh` and [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh).

Any ideas why this error is being thrown and how I can get around it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you tried to run `$ source ~/.vimrc` in the shell?

I think you want to reload your vimrc file from within vim:

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```

Maybe you confused this with running `$ source ~/.zshrc` from the shell.

Comment: I then get `E749: empty buffer` (recursive) when trying to open up `~/.vimrc` again. There seems to be a problem with the syntax of the vimrc file.

Comment: Hmm.. from the shell, try `vim ~/.vimrc` to open your rc file. Then `:so %` to source the current buffer (in this case your .vimrc) inside vim. That said, files in your plugins directory are sourced automatically.

Comment: Ah, that was just because I was in the wrong mode so it go written to the `.vimrc` file. You were right, I was getting confused with `source ~/.zshrc`. :) This _seems_ to now be correct(?) http://d.pr/i/1lORM/4Hrz0Nbo

Comment: Hmm syntax looks ok. As a side note, in your screenshot you have called `set laststatus=2` twice.

Comment: Ah yes, got it. I think it seems OK now. No strange symbols or errors resulting...